# Shopify Ajax Cart / Basic Jquery

Tags: ajax, shopify, cart

I'm trying to do the shopping cart featured here:
https://www.chubbiesshorts.com/

Specifically, I'm trying to figure out the AJAX Cart. My goal is to be able to allow the customers to add/subtract/manually enter the quantity and have it update the cart live (without the page reloading).

I've been able to construct everything except that feature. What exactly do I need to learn to make this happen? I'm willing to test, learn, do the work myself. I just literally have no idea where to start.

Apparently Shopify has an [AJAX cart API](https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api), and the theme I built my store off of, already has the AJAX cart enabled.

I guess that just means I need to learn how to call these functions and execute them.

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX Cart API page links to a laboratory page which links to the current api.jquery.js which is what some themes base their cart updates on.

If you put that file into an editor and format it you'll find it reads pretty well. You can also use Chrome's developer tools to view and pretty print the file.

Unfortunately this is not an event based api so if , for example you override Shopify.onCartUpdate you'll remove whatever the theme was expecting that to do.

However if your theme does what you want on a cart change but you want to supply an alternate way change what is in the cart (note example only works without line attributes:

```
 $.ajax({
    url:'/cart/update.js', 
    method:'POST', 
    dataType:'json', 
    contentType: "application/json", 
    data:JSON.stringify({updates:{
      variant_id_to_add:1,
      variant_id_to_remove:0,
      variant_id_to_update:3
  }})} ).
  then(function(cart){
Shopify.onCartUpdate(cart);
```

});